# Преобразование множественного типа в число

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я изучаю TypeScript и у Фримена я увидел пример использования множественного типа number | string. И чтобы использовать переменную нам нужно привести к нужному нам типу.

Собственно метод:

```
static convertFtoC(temp: number | string):string{
    let value:number = (<number>temp).toPrecision ? <number>temp :
      parseFloat(<string>temp);
    return ((parseFloat(value.toPrecision(2))-32)/1.8).toFixed(1);
  }
```

Я понимаю, что используется условие (temp).toPrecision чтобы узнать имеет ли результат преобразования метод toPrecision. И далее мы либо присваиваем temp, либо parseFloat(temp).

Вопрос: почему, если передать в метод строку и преобразовать её просто: `let value:number = (<number>temp)`, то toPrecision не будет вызываться?

Comment: потому что у строки нет такого метода

Comment: @Grundy немного неверно отображался мой вопрос.
Я имел в виду, почему нельзя изменить первую строку тела метода на: let value:number = (<number>temp)?
value будет числом и у него будет метод toPrecision().

Comment: _`let value:number = (<number>temp)`? value будет числом_ - нет не будет.